# JVM instruction ALOAD_0 in the 'main' method points to 'args' instead of 'this'?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, instructions, jasmin

I am trying to implement a subset of Java for an academic study. Well, I'm in the last stages (code generation) and I wrote a rather simple program to see how method arguments are handled:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args.length);
    }
}
```

Then I built it, and ran 'Main.class' through an online disassembler I found at:
http://www.cs.cornell.edu/People/egs/kimera/disassembler.html

I get the following implementation for the 'main' method:
(the disassembled output is in Jasmin)

```
.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    .limit locals 1
    .limit stack 2

    getstatic   java/lang/System/out Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    aload_0
    arraylength
    invokevirtual   java/io/PrintStream.println(I)V
    return
.end method
```

My problem with this is:
1. `aload_0` is supposed to push 'this' on to the stack (thats what the JVM spec seems to say)
2. `arraylength` is supposed to return the length of the array whose reference is on the top-of-stack

So according to me the combination of 1 & 2 should not even work.

How/why is it working? Or is the disassembler buggy and the actual bytecode is something else?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> aload_0 is supposed to push 'this' on to the stack

Not quite … `aload_0` reads the *first reference argument* (or, more generally, the first local reference variable) of the method and pushes it onto the stack.

In member functions, the first local variable happens to be the `this` reference.

But `main` is not a member function, it’s a *static* function so there is no `this` argument, and the true first argument of the method is `args`.

Comment: Does this hold true for *all* static methods?

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Don't think above statement is correct. `aload_0` reads the instance on which this method is invoked (i.e. `this` variable) and `aload_1` reads 1st argument to this method (from the local variable array of the current frame and pushed onto the operand stack). Ref JVM document for SE8 (also section 2.6) [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokespecial]

Comment: @BuckCherry And what happens for static methods? For clarification, see the first comment, by "grinch".

Comment: @grinch - I ready didn't get `this.foo(x,y) is really Foo.foo(this, x, y)`. Are you saying for static method, aload_0 reads current-class onto stack!!

Comment: @KonradRudolph - The meaning of aload_<n> is precisely, as the JVM doc says, to load reference typed value from local-array at index 'n' onto operand stack. For static methods, arguments are stored from index 0,1,.. as opposed to from 1,2,.. for non-static method. Either way, statements like- aload_0 reads 1st arg or 'this' are incorrect without referring to the static or no-static context. In fact, for a static method if 1st argument is not of 'reference' type, then there would be no aload_0 for that method. Btw, it would be nice if you could reflect that in your answer.

Comment: @BuckCherry I’ve made some clarifications. But your concern seems to be unrelated, and ultimately based on a misreading of the documentation: the JVM makes no difference between `this` and other arguments, and it makes no difference in its treatment of static and non-static methods (after invocation).

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Conceptually, a JVM doesn't need to bother about knowing which index stores what. However, JVM (SE8) does mandate the behavior and w.r.t. static and non-static aspects. Excerpts from sec. 2.6.1 of the spec. -*`"On class method invocation, any parameters are passed in consecutive local variables starting from local variable 0. On instance method invocation, local variable 0 is always used to pass a reference to the object on which the instance method is being invoked (this in the Java programming language)...."`*

Comment: @BuckCherry I know what the documentation says. It doesn’t support your claim.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Would you clearly state which claim you're referring to!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131164/discussion-between-buckcherry-and-konrad-rudolph).

Comment: @KGhatak No, what I meant is that a member function call like `this.foo(x,y)` is really just treated as a static function that passes the `this` reference as a parameter. So it turns into `Foo.foo(this, x, y)`

Comment: @grinch Not sure if this way of explaining (conversion between static and non-static methods) has any basis! Seems to me not so right!

Comment: @KGhatak I'm just saying that at the bytecode level the code is more like a bunch of static method calls with a `this` parameter being passed around.

Comment: @grinch - I don't mean to dwell on this so long...but even at bytecode level we have certain differentiation between static and non-static e.g. getfield vs. getstatic, invokespecial vs. invokestatic are JVM instructions that do differentiate static and non-static contexts.

Comment: @KGhatak yes I understand there are differences between static and non static. When I made the comment 5 years ago I was just pointing out that the call in java: `this.foo(x,y)` is more like this in byte code: `Foo.foo(this, x, y)`.